# Unable to implement update item in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I am currently experiencing a strange issue with the update part of CRUD. Creating, reading and deleting items work perfectly well but for some reason when I try to update, nothing happens and my app remains on the same page.

In summary this is the flow an edit button is clicked to call up a modal with the form and values of the item. Then changes are made and the form submitted by clicking the save changes button and nothing happens.

Here's the code I am working with

route

```
Route::put('/home/testimonials/{testimonial}/update', 'TestimonialController@update');
```

TestimonialController update function

```
public function update(Request $request, Testimonial $testimonial)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

Edit modal form

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="/home/testimonials/{{$item->id}}/update" method="POST">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{$item->firstname}}" class="form-control" aria-describedby="firstname">
                <small id="firstname" class="text-muted">Firstname</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" value="{{$item->lastname}}" class="form-control" aria-describedby="lastname">
                <small id="lastname" class="text-muted">Lastname</small>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Comment</label>
            <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" aria-describedby="comment">{{$item->comment}}</textarea>
            <small id="comment" class="text-muted">Client's comment</small>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-one">Save Changes</button>
</div>
```

I need help figuring out when I see nothing when i try to dump the form values when form is submitted.

Comment: Why is your `<button>` out of your `<form>`?

Comment: also your form has method POST, but it should have PUT. and also in your update function, why is the second parameter the model? it should be $id.

Comment: @Mozammil the button is inside the modal footer. Placing it inside gives me the same result

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze HTML forms do no support PUT method so I'm using the hidden PUT method with blade directive method

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Model binding? If not, could you change your `update()` method to the following and give it a try?

```
public function update($testimonial, Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using model binding.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't say why my code failed initially but by simply deleting the modal part and writing it again, my code worked.